# Tipo de dato para almacenar coordenadas Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Buenas noches tengo una base de datos en Postgresql y deseo añadir dos campos para almacenar la latitud y longitud, lei en varios blogs que el campo deberua ser flotante (float), y mi pregunta en concreto es si es esta afirmacion correcta y si lo es que dimfnsion deberia tener??

Comment: De hecho se pueden guardar los dos en un mismo campo puedes crear tu tipo de campo o usar los de postres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías usar `DECIMAL` o en el caso de PostgreSQL su equivalente es `NUMERIC` pues te va a permitir hacer operaciones matemáticas sobre los datos que almacenes

Un ejemplo de la declaración debería ser de este modo:

```
CREATE TABLE ubicaciones(
   ubicacion VARCHAR(10),
   latitud NUMERIC(10,8),
   longitud NUMERIC(10,8)
 );
```

Ya que al ser coordenadas vas a necesitar calcular: distancia, promedios, etc

Como tu mismo puedes comprobar en la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype.html) para el área de tipos dice

1. NUMERIC => Es un dato exacto de una precisión seleccionable
2. DOUBLE => Número de coma flotante de doble presición

Por lo cual veo que double se puede volver ambiguo y riesgoso usarlo

Inlcuso otra opción es que a través de PostgreSQL uses los datos de tipo JSON para guardar ambos registros en una misma columna, te dejo un ejemplo

```
CREATE TABLE paises(
   ubicacion VARCHAR(10),
   precisiones JSON
 );
```

Posterior insertarías los datos de este modo

```
INSERT INTO paises(ubicacion, donde) 
VALUES('Mexico', '{"latitud": "19.1571124", "longitud": "19.4875414"}');
```

Y finalmente al leerlos se verían de este modo:

```
SELECT * FROM datos;

ubicacion   donde
Mexico      {"latitud": "19.1571124", "longitud": "19.4875414"}
```